# Drawing charts(pie or bar) on map Arcgis Api for javascript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, chart

I googled this for a long time now . I am looking for a way to draw or add charts on map in any way.
I am using DynamicLayer and can query on any field and any layer but the is no way to draw charts.
There is InfoWindow/MapTip but it needs clicking on the map and that is not what we are looking for because of the clicking and mouse over need.

[image]

Something like this.

Comment: I would look into https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/picturemarkersymbol-amd.html and svg or an api to generate static pie chart images or possibly a custom renderer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well...since there is no feature in JSAPI satisfying the need, I created a server-side solution for making the charts and the drawing it using "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol" .
[image]
I explain the solution step by step.

First of all I make the charts using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting on server-side code. This will save the png files on a specific folder in the solution . (The code for creating charts using this class is out there , so I did not provide any undue code )

```
string FileStr = LpInfo[i].ObjId + "_" + LayerName + ".png";
chart1.SaveImage(AppRoot + FileStr,ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

I save the png files using objectId and the LayerName separated with underline character to address the files.
After creating the charts, I just need to query through the Layer and draw the pngs using "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol". To draw each chart for each feature I just need to make an address for the files.for example :

```
var markerUrl = "images/PngCharts/" + PreFolderN +   
features[i].attributes[ObjIdFieldName] + "_" + LayerName + ".PNG";
```

This solution has 2 parts. So if you want to make it happen an one click, I suggest you to create a webmethod to create the charts and then in the callBack, query through the requested LayerName and draw the charts.

I should mention that this solution is not the only way of doing that but it's the easiest method I could think of. It does have the flexibility and it is fast enough. So if anyone can provide a better solution I would be happy to read that!

Comment: you saved my time

Comment: In one of our systems we display stack bars (instead of pie charts), but the approach is the same i.e. dynamically draw the PNG files in the back-end.